# Transparency in pie charts

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, transparency-opacity, chart

I was able to make my pie charts in one mxd transparent, which I prefer, but I cannot replicate it. When I try to look it up it seems pie charts can't be made transparent. They are two different layers but both are point layers. I just adjusted the transparency in one but for the second even when I adjust it nothing changed.

[image: transparent pie chart]

[image: opaque pie chart]

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to make your point symbols transparent.  I don't think its even possible if you use the Convert the Features to Graphics tools.  The only way to do it would be to export to another software and edit your transparency there, but it wouldn't be in your MXD anymore.

Comment: but I am able to do it in some mxds, some are based on a point layer another works with a polygon layer, the third doesn't work with a point layer. Not sure why it works sometimes and not others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only set the transparency if you symbolize say a point feature as a chart which in your case is pie chart. Please see the Symbology tab of your feature class. After this, you can set the transparency of your feature class from the Display tab and this will reflect on the pie charts.

[image]

Comment: you are right, I was confused because I thought I had a polygon layer that it was working on, but after converting my polygon layer to points I can set the transparency.